# Is it possible to detect changes by participants to Google Calendar events?

Tags: api, calendar, google-calendar-api

Consider the following scenario:
I have a web application where visitors are able to book events in the admin's Google Calendar. I need to perform some actions on the server in case a booked event is cancelled / deleted by the Admin or the visitor in their Google Calendar Account. Do note that the actions I need to perform are different if the event is cancelled by admin or by the visitor.

The question: Is this feature possible with Google Calendar API?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the tool you are looking for is the `watch` in the Google Calendar API. https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/push#making-watch-requests

The overall workflow is that you have to send a request to Google to configure the watch on the calendar with a specific URL to receive the upcoming notifications. Then Google sends a notification to the specified URL every time there is a change on the Google calendar.

Edit: The notification Google sends does not include the modification done to the calendar. You then have to get the calendar events to see what's been updated. You should use [sync token](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/sync) to get only the updated event from the calendar once you have done a full sync.

Comment: I have tried this. Unfortunately there is no indication in the response about who modified the event (the visitor or the admin). I need to perform different actions in my web application depending on who cancelled / deleted the event.

Comment: Yes, it's expected to do so. After receiving the notification, you have to query the calendar to get the updated events. I edited my answer with more details.